# Multi-day event in iPhone calendar

Tags: iphone, calendar

I want to add an event but the event is added in all the days. If I add an event which has a last date after 10 days, then the event is added today and all the days between today and 10 days from now. I want to just add the event at the end date, not between these days. How can I do this?

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = appDelegate.Name;
event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
event.endDate   = appDelegate.Date_iCal;
//event.allDay    = NO;
[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Comment: obviously you did something wrong in your code. I would point you at the exact line but unfortunately you didn't provide code.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but what do you want to do? When should the event really start? Currently the event starts now (= `[[NSDate alloc] init]`) and ends at the date specified by Date_iCal.

Comment: let suppose today is 17th march, i want to add event on 25 march, this event is add on 17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25 march.but i just want to add event on 25 march not others date.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify the correct start date.

Right now you do this

```
event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init]; // today
event.endDate   = appDelegate.Date_iCal; // in the future
```

and this will obviously add an event that starts now and ends somewhere in the future.

I don't know anything about your event, so you have to figure out the start and end of it on your own.